# How to test in different environments with gherkin/cucumber.js

Tags: gherkin, cucumberjs

I am using gherkin and cucumber.js.

For the moment my tests are running into the same environment. I would like to choose the environment when I run the scripts. I saw that there is the "config" param to do that:

```
./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --config=QUALITY
```

I have understood that in this case I must create separate files which will contain the different values (for example the "endpoint url", the "database credentials', etc..)

But impossible to find any more documentation about that.

Someone could share an example ?